# How to add Firebase to Codename One iOS app?

Tags: ios, firebase, codenameone

I am trying to add Firebase to my Codename One iOS app. 
I've read up on how to add Native Interfaces in Codename One and have successfully added the CocoaPods for Firebase as well. However, being unfamiliar with Objective-C and iOS in general (I've never worked on an iOS app outside of the Codename One framework), I'm not sure how to integrate these instructions from the Firebase website into my interface:

```
@import UIKit;
@import Firebase;

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
  [FIRApp configure];
  return YES;
}
```

As well as the instructions here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/ios/start?authuser=0, 
specifically:

> Import the Firebase module in your UIApplicationDelegate subclass:
>
> OBJECTIVE-C
>
> `@import Firebase;`
>
> Configure a FirebaseApp shared instance, typically in your application's `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method:
>
> OBJECTIVE-C
>
> `// Use Firebase library to configure APIs`
>
> `[FIRApp configure];`

I added the `.plist` file to my `native` -> `ios` folder.

**EDIT:** I want to use the following Firebase features: analytics and crash reporting to start with, eventually notifications.

Can someone advise how this would be done?

Thanks!

Comment: what you need in fire base?

Comment: Which features of Firebase are you planning on using - authentication, realtime database, push notifications, etc. That first needs to be known before anyone can provide suggestions to point you in the right direction

Comment: Thanks. Please see edited question.

Answer (score 0):

Add the build hints:

```
ios.afterFinishLaunching=[FIRApp configure];
ios.glAppDelegateHeader=#import <Firebase/Firebase.h>
```

The rest of the things you can just invoke in the native interface code. Notice the tip to wrap the code in async blocks https://www.codenameone.com/blog/tip-use-native-edt.html

Comment: Thanks but I am getting these errors when trying to compile after adding the build hints:  `/var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build4936122916482639282xxx/dist/Myapp-src/CodenameOne_GLAppDelegate.m:39:1: error: use of '@import' when modules are disabled
@import Firebase` AND 
`/var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build4936122916482639282xxx/dist/Myapp-src/CodenameOne_GLAppDelegate.m:206:6: error: use of undeclared identifier 'FIRApp'
    [FIRApp configure]`

Comment: Try replacing `@import` with `#import <Firebase/Firebase.h>`

Comment: Thanks. Can you please advise me about how to handle the error related to `FIRAPP` and `[FIRAPP configure] `?

Comment: If the import will work the API usage should work too